# ¿Cómo obtener la zona horaria del cliente usando Node.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, express, momentjs

actualmente especifico la zona horaria manualmente en un a API de esta forma

```
router.post('/hora-zona-horaria',(req: Request, res: Response) => {
  
  // req.body.from = 2021-06-28T09:00:00
  let hora = momentz.tz(req.body.from, "America/El_Salvador");

  // responde: 2021-06-28T15:00:00
  console.log(hora);

  res.json({hora_zona_horaria: hora});

});
```

lo que quisiera saber como puedo obtener la zona horaria del cliente según donde lo consulte el cliente, por ejemplo que en el mismo instante uno lo consulte en Centro América y el otro lo consulte en Estados Unidos, y pueda obtener su zona horaria.

**IMPORTANTE:** el servidor Node.js lo tengo corriendo en digitalOcean por lo cual ahi se utiliza horario UTC

Comment: Es el cliente el que te tiene que pasar la hora, el servidor siempre te va a dar la misma, no importa si es node, iis o apache, en el cliente tienes que recuperar la fecha y enviartela al servidor, un [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39161134/10053314)

Comment: O podrías usar métodos nada fiables basados en [*IP Lookup* para determinar la zona horaria](https://ipgeolocation.io/timezone-api.html) basada en la ubicación geográfica del cliente que realiza la petición a tu servidor. No sé si existan otras alternativas. Saludos